# confusion about error correction model

Tags: regression, cointegration, ecm

I came across the following model in an internal paper:

> $∆y_t=\beta (\mu-y_{t-1} ) +\kappa(x_{t} -\alpha y_{t-1} ) +\epsilon_t$........................(1)

In this the first part :  $\beta(\mu-y_{t-1})$  , signifies the mean reversion

while the second part : $\kappa(x_t -\alpha y_{t-1} )$ , signifies the last forecasting error

Also, the regression

> $x_t =\alpha y_{t-1} $

is run separately to estimate $\alpha$ (and establish that intercept =0).

The authors call the model (1) an error correction model. Somehow I am not able to link it to a regular error correction model of the form:

> $ ∆y_t = β0 + β1∆x_t + \kappa(x_{t−1} − \alpha y_{t−1}) + u_t $

because in regular model, we have short run dynamics and some deviation from the long run equilibrium that we expect to be corrected. In model (1) however, both the terms seem to be linked to deviations from long run equilibrium relations.

Is it ok to call the model (1) an error correction model?